# Did Pope Francis say that the Gospel is radical?

Tags: catholicism, pope-francis

I vaguely remember a quote by Pope Francis, in the context of mercy and his apostolic exhortation *Amoris Laetitia*, which goes something like "The teaching of the Gospel itself is quite radical", using "radical" in a good way.  The basic meaning of the  quote was somethng like, Pope Francis doesn't need to break new ground in placing a greater emphasis on God's mercy and forgiveness, because the Gospel's teaching on this is already quite earth-shattering if we just listen to it.

Can someone help me identify this quote?  I distinctly remember that the words "Gospel" and "radical" occur in the quote.

I can't seem to find it in *Amoris Laetitia*, but it's possible that it's from some interview he gave about it, or it's from another document authored by him.

Comment: I found a few quotes on vatican.va with radical evangelization, but not that the gospel was itself radical.  Although his Holiness does seem to enoy the term.

Comment: Although it's maybe hard to find an exact quote, there seem to be plenty of people using the word when talking about what Pope Francis says.

Comment: I think his is a poor choice of words to say 'which is according to the ways of the world radical'. As it is he is making occasion for a lots of confusion. Analagously, he also said the 'failure of the cross', whereas I think he meant, in all honesty, to say 'what seemed to be the apparent failure of the cross'. In the sense that the Lord's disciples indeed viewed this as a failure.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything quite like this in the context of *Amoris Laetitia*, but the pope has used the words together a few times. According to [the English-language version of the Vatican Radio website](http://en.radiovaticana.va/news/2014/09/23/pope_francis_at_mass_christian_life_simple,_radical/1107120), he preached a homily from his residence in Santa Marta on 23 September 2014 in which he spoke about "the Gospel's call to radical simplicity in life and action". Similarly, in [a homily preached for the 6th Asian Youth Day in Korea on 16 August 2014](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/homilies/2014/documents/papa-francesco_20140816_corea-omelia-beatificazione.pdf) (PDF), he spoke about "the radical demands of the Gospel". I can't find much else using precisely those words in documents published by the Pope, and nothing about interviews in which he used those words (though that is a more difficult search, especially with off-the-cuff remarks).

Francis was not the first to use "radical" in speaking about the Gospel, though; Pope St John Paul II mentioned the "radicalism of the Gospel" in his 1992 apostolic exhortation [*Pastores Dabo Vobis*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/apost_exhortations/documents/hf_jp-ii_exh_25031992_pastores-dabo-vobis.html), and Pope Benedict XVI spoke of the "radical call of the Gospel" in [an address to the bishops of Bangladesh](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/speeches/2008/june/documents/hf_ben-xvi_spe_20080612_ad-limina-bangladesh.html) during their *ad limina* visit in 2008.